# diff handling of C++ template code between clang++ and cl.exe

Tags: c++, windows, templates, llvm-ir, cl.exe

I got a piece of c++ code which could be compiled well with cl.exe (msvc 2019) by the command line of "cl.exe tt.cpp -c".
Here is the code piece.

```
using void_t = void;

template <class _Ty, class = void>
struct _Add_reference { 
    using _Lvalue = _Ty;
    using _Rvalue = _Ty;
};


template <class _Ty>
struct _Add_reference<_Ty, void_t<_Ty&>> { 
    using _Lvalue = _Ty&;
    using _Rvalue = _Ty&&;
};

template <class _Ty>
using add_lvalue_reference_t = typename _Add_reference<_Ty>::_Lvalue;

template <class _Ty> 
constexpr bool _Is_copy_assignable_unchecked_v = __is_assignable_no_precondition_check(
    add_lvalue_reference_t<_Ty>, 
    add_lvalue_reference_t<const _Ty>
);
```

Here is the command line with cl.exe:

`>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe" -c tt.cpp`

While when I use clang.exe ( 12.0.0) to convert it to llvm ir (or just object file), I got some errors.
Here is the command line with clang++.exe which issues some error message.

`>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin\clang++.exe" -c tt.cpp`
or
`>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\Llvm\bin\clang++.exe"  -S -emit-llvm tt.cpp`
Error message:

```
tt.cpp:24:29: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
        add_lvalue_reference_t<_Ty>,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
tt.cpp:26:1: error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
);
^
2 errors generated.
```

Any comments on the above error in the scenario of clang++.exe?
Thanks.

Comment: `__is_assignable_no_precondition_check` is most likely a MSVC library internal helper, and you can't count on that existing with other compilers.  Also not that names like `_Add_reference` are reserved, and it is UB to use them.

Comment: To clang, the code looks like `foo(int, float)`. `__is_assignable_no_precondition_check` is a MSVC-specific intrinsic

Comment: You can see how MSVC handles this in order to let clang work with their version of the standard library here: https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/178b8406a5647507e759442960f17cd33045cdf5/stl/inc/type_traits#L636

Comment: Thanks Frank. I checked the content of C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\include\type_traits and tried to pass /U _IS_ASSIGNABLE_NOCHECK_SUPPORTED to "cl.exe /E ..." to avoid something;   but the pre-processed result still has those code pieces.

Comment: Thanks Nathan for the comments. Are you saying that it may be not available to process such kind of code pieces via llvm toolchains?

Comment: @dac what I'm saying is that you need to do the same thing Microsoft did: Only use `__is_assignable_no_precondition_check()` if `_IS_ASSIGNABLE_NOCHECK_SUPPORTED` is set. Falling back on `std::is_copy_assignable` is probably the best you can do otherwise.

Comment: @dac Yes.  each compiler has it's own set of helper functions it uses. You can't use the helper functions from compiler A with compiler B, at least not portably.

Comment: Yup. I modified the pre-processed code by applying std::is_copy_assignable only, it works well as far as I could see. I did  the same thing as the workaround for the bug of https://www.mail-archive.com/llvm-bugs@lists.llvm.org/msg34175.html. But my goal is to create some tools which will use msvc toolchain to process user's code. It is just a workaround to create/modify the pre-processed code.  I do not know if there are any other options.

Comment: Thanks again all for the suggestions and comments. I will do a more test to see if those modifications on pre-processed code work.